# how to set a python program to read an unspecified number of scores and determine how many scores are above average and below average

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this much already i just don't understand how to make it read an unspecified number.

```
NUMBER_OF_SCORES = (1-100):
numbers = [] 

sum = 0

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_SCORES): 
    value = eval(input("Enter a new number: ")) 
    numbers.append(value)

    sum += value

average = sum / NUMBER_OF_SCORES

count = 0 # The number of elements above average

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_SCORES): 
    if numbers[i] > average:     
        count += 1

count1 = 0

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_SCORES): 
    if numbers[i] < average:
        count1 += 1

stop = "stop"

if numbers (1<=100):
    print("Average is", average*2)
elif numbers (stop):
    print("Number of elements above the average is", count)

else:
    print("sorry i don't understand.")"
```

Comment: I tried to tidy this up a bit - it'd be useful for future posts if you look at how to format codeblocks correctly. I'll also point out this isn't syntactically correct code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "read on unspecified number of scores", maybe you want a loop and the user hits <kbd>ctrl+D</kbd> to stop?  You can do this by catching `EOFError` from `input()`.

```
scores = []
while True:
    try:
        scores.append(int(input('Enter a score: ')))
    except EOFError:
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('invalid number')
print()
average = sum(scores) / len(scores)
print('Average: {}'.format(average))
print('Number of scores above average: {}'
      .format(sum(x > average for x in scores)))
```

Output:

```
Enter a score: 1
Enter a score: 2
Enter a score: 3
Enter a score: 4
Enter a score: ctrl+D
Average: 2.5
Number of scores above average: 2
```

As mentioned, `eval` is dangerous and you should avoid it.  **DO NOT ATTEMPT THE FOLLOWING:**

```
Enter a score: __import__('os').system('rm -rf $HOME')
```

Comment: thany you very much. And sorry for the ambiguity. I meant a user defined number of scores.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is awkwardly phrased, but I think by *'read an unspecified number'* what you are looking for is generating a random value - in which case, you want `random.randint()`.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(1, 100)
17
>>> random.randint(1, 100)
30
>>> random.randint(1, 100)
84
```

Also note that you don't need to do so many loops to achieve what you are trying to do. If you are looping over a range of indices in python rather than looping over the list itself, you are doing something wrong. In this case, it's far easier to use [the built in `sum()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

```
>>> import random
>>> numbers = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)]
>>> numbers
[45, 81, 46, 80, 67, 57, 72, 47, 87, 13, 5, 56, 87, 5, 74, 7, 88, 1, 36, 48, 97, 39, 16, 31, 52, 30, 14, 58, 43, 17, 70, 85, 37, 49, 28, 1, 33, 73, 90, 86, 75, 42, 27, 91, 100, 86, 59, 85, 43, 59, 27, 24, 11, 56, 95, 36, 3, 10, 40, 42, 10, 71, 75, 10, 69, 86, 63, 6, 56, 95, 91, 31, 40, 13, 5, 5, 31, 28, 36, 94, 22, 77, 100, 36, 98, 85, 23, 61, 92, 94, 17, 91, 25, 43, 55, 7, 9, 57, 14, 39]
>>> average = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
>>> average
49
>>> sum(number > average for number in numbers)
46
>>> sum(number < average for number in numbers)
53
```

Here I have also used [list comprehensions and generator expressions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY), which are useful for these kind of operations.

Alongside this, `eval()` is a really bad way to get a number from a string. Use `int(some_string)` instead.

Comment: `average = sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))` ?

Comment: @JonClements As he uses ``eval()`` on ``input()``, we can presume he is using 3.x, where we don't need to do that. In 2.x, that or ``from __future__ import division`` would be necessary.

Comment: @JonClements It's better than forgetting it the other way around. I hate it whenever I have to move back to 2.x these days.

Comment: @Lattyware Thank you for the help, and yea my professor is making us run everything in 3.2. I've learned more from the people on stackoverflow than my professor though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what you mean by unspecified. If you want it to be user determined, you can pass it in as an argument, eg

```
import sys

NUMBER_SCORES=sys.argv[1]
```

or with an actual argument parsing package like argparse.

Or you can prompt the user for a number of scores before reading in the scores.

@Lattyware has a great answer for the random case.